# Plotly Python dynamic order of legend text

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, plotly.js

Good day!

I am trying to order my Plotly pie chart's legend. I have categories with the following names:

```
categories = [
'0-recognizing', 
'1-recalling', 
'2-interpreting', 
'3-exemplifying', 
'4-classifying', 
'5-summarizing', 
'6-inferring', 
'7-comparing', 
'8-explaining', 
'9-executing', 
'10-implementing'
]
```

The default legend order I get is:

```
0-recognizing
1-recalling 
10-implementing
2-interpreting 
3-exemplifying 
4-classifying 
5-summarizing 
6-inferring
7-comparing
8-explaining 
9-executing
```

I need this to display in the correct order and not insert `'10-implementing'` between 1 and 2.

The pie charts are created using Plotly in Python. Then they are displayed in a webpage using Plotly JS.

How do I get the legend to display correctly? Thanks!

Comment: The legend order and legend groups may help you. For more information, see [here](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#legend-order).